# Embed an external shiny app in another vanilla shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I want to embed an external shiny app in another *vanilla* shiny app and run this app including the nested / embedded app on my local machine.

In RMarkdown this is [well documented](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/shiny.html#external_applications) and can be easily done by using `shinyAppDir()` in an R chunk within a flexdashboard.

My question is: How can this be done in a pure vanilla shiny context (without relying on RMarkdown and flexdashboard)? I gave it a first try with putting `shinyAppDir` in a `renderUI` statement, but that is not working (which makes sense, since the app is not only made of UI, but also contains server logic).

Here is a working example of an embedded shiny app in a flexdashboard:

This is a simple shiny app I want to embed:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      textInput("min_e", "min eruptions", min(faithful$eruptions)),
      textInput("max_e", "max eruptions", max(faithful$eruptions)),
      actionButton(inputId = "OK", label = "OK")
    ),

    mainPanel( plotOutput("distPlot1")

    )

  )


),

  server = function(input, output) {

    nbins = reactive({input$OK
                     isolate(input$bins)})

     faithful_filtered = reactive({input$OK

      faithful %>% filter(eruptions >= isolate(input$min_e),
                          eruptions <= isolate(input$max_e))

      })

    output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
      x <- faithful_filtered()[, 2]  # Old Faithful Geyser data
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out =  nbins() + 1)
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })




  }

)
```

And it can be embedded in a flexdashboard like this (if you run this code make sure to first save the app above (as app.R) and enter the correct file path in `shinyAppDir()`).

````
---
title: "embedded shiny"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: column
runtime: shiny
---


```{r, include=FALSE, message=FALSE, context="setup"}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)

```

Input {.sidebar data-width=300}
-------------------------------------

```{r, echo=FALSE, context="render"}
sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30)
actionButton(inputId = "OK", label = "OK")
```

```{r, context="server"}


```

Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Some plot here

```{r, context="server"}

```

```{r, echo=FALSE}

```

### Another plot here

```{r, context="server"}

```

```{r, echo=FALSE}

```

### Embeded app here

```{r, echo=FALSE}
shinyAppDir(
  file.path("file_path_goes_here"), # enter valid file path here
  options=list(
    width="100%", height=700
  )
)
```
````